# mysqli_fetch_field_direct wrong result

Tags: mariadb

I was using mysqli_fetch_field_direct on MySQL to get length of fields, using :

```
 $tab_field = mysqli_fetch_field_direct($result_fields,$j);
 $long = $tab_field->length;
```

After creating a varchar(100) under PhpMyAdmin, I got back 100 as my varchar length which was correct.

Now, I'm using MariaDB and the same call to mysqli_fetch_field_direct for the same field, give me 300. I accept the fact that, according to the encoding, maybe it's the "internal size", but I need to know the number of char I can put, so I need to get back "100".
I notice that PhpMyAdmin return 100 when it shows the "structure" of the table, but it seems to use a SHOW query rather than fetch_field_direct.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Let's see `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  I'll guess that the column is declared `CHAR(100)`?  And the old version was `CHARACTER SET latin1`?  And the MariaDB one was `CHARACTER SET utf8`?

Generally `VARCHAR` is preferred over `CHAR`.  (You found one reason.)

Generally `utf8` is preferred these days.

Comment: Well in fact, I decided to use select * from information_schema.COLUMNS  where table_name = 'XXX' . I get the size I wanted (100) in the CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH and the size which I get from mysqli_fetch_field_direct in the CHARACTER_OCTET_LENGTH.  From the begining (MySQL) I used utf8.